# Prevent External Link indicator graphic from displaying on images

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink

I've added the following bit to my CSS:

```
#content a[target^="_blank"] {
    background-image:url(images/extlink.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 12px;
}
```

This gives a little external link indicator (seen on Wikipedia) on all of the links that open in a new window.  The issue is it also does this for linked images.  Obviously, I don't want to have that graphic on images.  Anyone have an idea on how to get around this?

**Edit**
Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move those styles to a CSS class called external, this jQuery code should work (untested):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('target') == '_blank') && $(this).find('img').length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('external');
    }
});
```

Comment: I like that idea more then what I was doing.  I was trying it by doing the following 'jQuery('a img').parent().css('padding-right', '0');' and that was working.  I haven't been able to get yours to work, but I'd prefer your method.